# Word opens extra blank document

Tags: ms-word

I have an issue on a client machine that seems to be interferring with a word addin that ive built.

When any word document opens on the client machine, a second blank document opens also.

Ive seen this issue on a number of different machines but havent seen an explanation as to why.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour in word and have you managed to stop the second document opening?

Cheers

Comment: Does the problem really only manifest when you have the addin installed? How is the addin delivered?

Comment: the problem is a word issue, its not caused by the addin, rather i believe its affecting the behaviour of teh addin, which is why im trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue is happening regardless of whether or not your addin is installed, perhaps the user has a strange macro running in their default template file (normal.dot)?

You could try replacing normal.dot with a version from a machine which doesn't have the problem to see if that helps!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are delivering your addin as a .dot, it is very easy to accidentally set it up to have a document in it that opens. This, of course, assumes that the problem follows the addin. If it does not follow the addin then you don't have a programming problem.

Comment: true, i dont have a programming problem. This issue happens without the addin installed. Its a generic word issue that seems to be affecting my addin, not the other way round

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me in Windows Explorer when the preview pane is enabled on it.
If you double-click a word document then 2 instances of Word open, one of them is with empty document.
Disabling the preview pane eliminates the problem.